# AJAX it's not receiving the data back from the php file

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to send some values ​​through ajax and after being treated in the test.php, send the data back to be used.

The database part is correct. My problem is in the re-sending of the data:
The Json coding part does not give error, but when I try to check the data, many of them do not appear.

I think this can be caused by:

The way I am resending the data;

The way I encode Json.

My code.

ajax main.php:

```
$('#filtro_limit1').val(num_Limite_rows);
$.ajax({
    url: teste.php,
    type:'post',
    data:
        {
            limite: num_Limite_rows,
            tipologia: tipologia_val,
            ordenar_por: ordenar_por_val
        },
    success: function(data, num_rows, num_actual_rows, mensagem_erro)
    {

    }
});
```

PHP teste.php:

```
if(pg_num_rows($result1) > 0)
{
  $data = array[];
  $data = $result1;
  $out = array_values($data);
  echo json_encode($out);
  echo pg_num_rows($result1);
  echo $filtro_limit;
  echo "Não existem erros";
}
else
{
  $data = array[];
  echo json_encode($data);
  $numero_rows = 0;
  echo $total_rows;
  echo $filtro_limit;
  echo "Não existem valores a serem mostrados";
}
```

Please some help needed. Thank you for the future help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success function is wrong. The parameter `data` will contain all the output of your php script. You can't automatically split the output by using different parameters in the function definition.

```
function success(data, textStatus, jgXHR) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Check your console and you'll see your data.

You'll probably want to change your php code:

```
$result = [
  'out' => json_encode($out),
  'result1' => pg_num_rows($result1),
  'filtro_limit' => $filtro_limit,
  'message' => "Não existem erros",
]
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

and

```
$result = [
  'total_rows' => $total_rows,
  'filtro_limit' => $filtro_limit,
  'message' => "Não existem valores a serem mostrados",
];
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

That way, you'll have a much easier time to parse the data in JavaScript. For example:

```
function success(data, textStatus, jgXHR) {
    var message = data.message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to return all data in one statement in php like this :

```
echo json_encode(array(
'out'=>$out,
'num_rows'=>pg_num_rows($result1),
'filtro_limit'=>$filtro_limit,
'msg'=>"Não existem valores a serem mostrados"
));
```

and ajax code like this:

```
$('#filtro_limit1').val(num_Limite_rows);
$.ajax({
    url: 'teste.php',
    type:'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:
        {
            limite: num_Limite_rows,
            tipologia: tipologia_val,
            ordenar_por: ordenar_por_val
        },
    success: function(data)
    {
        $num_rows=data['num_rows'];
    }
});
```